# What regression approach should I use for this dataset?

Tags: regression, mixed-model

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
COUNTY    YEAR    PREDICTOR1   PREDICTOR2  DEATHRATE
ADAMS     2014    34.3         34.1        4.5
ADAMS     2015    32.1         67.3        5.5
ADAMS     2016    34.2         33.2        6.7
JONES     2014    33.6         47.3        20.3
JONES     2015    33.6         29.3        39.3
JONES     2016    98.3         25.3        33.3
```

So, it's data at the county-level for 4 years, without about 288 observations.  There's about 10 predictors variables and the response variable is the deathrate (overdose death rate per capita).

I've been reading about this and it sounds like I need a mixed-effects model to account for the fact that there are multiple observations per county.

I will be doing the statistical analysis in R so if anyone could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it!  I've tried using glmer in R but something must have not been right because it literally ran all day.

Thanks!

Comment: So you have these predictors and your response variable - the death rate. Where exactly does the "time series" part come in? I see different times, but do you only have 2014, 2015 and 2016 data for each county?

Comment: Hi, in my actual data, I have 2017-2020 data for each county.  edited my question, as maybe this isn't time series data.

Comment: Hm. Well, I would say that with only 5 years and therefore 5 "time series" data points, you don't have enough longitudinal data to really treat this as a time series problem. I would try to approach the problem by just ignoring the time series aspect.

Comment: I agree with your assessment that mixed effects model is probably what you need. (Unfortunately, I don't have any experience with that)